# Spaces in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I am grouping together words from a mysql column and counting the number of appearances.  This is working fine except that sometimes it lists a word count of 1 when the table column is actually empty.  I am assuming that this must just be a space or something in the column.

I have tried trim to remove the space but it cleans up the space with the other words but still returns a value of one and an empty field.

Is trim the correct method?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: A field containing whitespace is NOT empty. Just because it appears empty to us doesn't mean it actually is empty. Same situation with the 'empty' Coke can on your desk - it's still full of air.

Comment: Thanks, i guess that just don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats your MySQL code? You could tell your query not to look for the empty fields.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE field != ''
OR field IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: There is no operator **!=** in MySQL - use **<>** instead.

Comment: the thing is where the information is being put in  automatically every time somebody visits, when there isn't a word to put in it seems to still make an entry, i did try null but it didn't seem to do anything and i assumed that maybe it was putting in a space or something if that makes sense.

Comment: $query = "SELECT string, COUNT(string) FROM ip_stats GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 5";   
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo  $row['COUNT(string)']; echo "\n";
 echo  $row['string'];
 echo "<br />";

Comment: I just tried your code but it is still turning out counts without a field.

Comment: Hi i used the <> with the above code but it just gave an error

Comment: @Rolice, there is in any halfway recent version of MySQL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Comment: @user1259446: SELECT string, COUNT(string) FROM ip_stats 
WHERE something != ''
OR something IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 5

Comment: Thanks, like Marc B said the fields whilst appear to be empty are not, so is there away to remove the white space or whatever it is in these fields?  Thanks

Comment: You don't need to remove it, you should just be able to not target it. You can use the != ' ' or IS NOT NULL. Have you tried doing that yet?

If you have and it definitely hasn't worked; do you have access to the database to see what is actually in that field?

Comment: Ok, it's actually working now:), just put your code back in again and it worked so i must have missed something or i don't know but it is working now.  Thanks you.   One more question though i want to sort the results by those with the highest count, i changed it so it grouped by string but that doesn't return the highest value first.  Again thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe GROUP BY id ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 5?

Comment: Wait, should be SELECT string, COUNT(string) as myCount FROM ip_stats, then use the ORDER BY, but ORDER BY myCount DESC LIMIT 5.

Comment: No it doesn't work, it says it column count doesn't exist.  Anyway again thanks for your help, i am going to call it a day now and look at it again tomorrow.  Thanks

Comment: See the comment above the one you just posted about the COUNT(string) as myCount. Also, if this is correct, would you mark this answer correct too? :)

Comment: Sorry, that worked perfect, i missed something out, but it worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad you've got it working! :) Underneath the two arrows, with the 0? There should be a hollowed out 'tick'. Click that,

Comment: You've got me +1 ;)
However, as in this case, without a version mentioned, I would use the old operator.